# Enabling UTS Namespaces in the Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel, configuration, linux-kernel, development

When configuring the Linux kernel, what are the advantages and disadvantages of enabling UTS namespaces? Would the new system be harmed if UTS namespaces were disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTS Namespaces are per-process namespaces allowing a process to have different namespaces for different resources. For example, a process could have a set of namespaces for the following:

- mountpoints
- PID numbers
- network stack state
- IPC - inter process communications

**NOTE:** the use of [namespaces was limited only to root up until version 3.8+](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.8#head-fc2604c967c200a26f336942caee2440a2a4099c) of the Linux Kernel.

#### unshare

You can use the command `unshare` to disassociate a parent's namespace from a child process.

```
$ unshare --help
Usage: unshare [options] <program> [args...]
Run program with some namespaces unshared from parent

  -h, --help        usage information (this)
  -m, --mount       unshare mounts namespace
  -u, --uts         unshare UTS namespace (hostname etc)
  -i, --ipc         unshare System V IPC namespace
  -n, --net         unshare network namespace

For more information see unshare(1).
```

#### compiler option

- [CONFIG_UTS_NS](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/UTS_NS.html)

> Support uts namespaces. This allows containers, i.e. vservers, to use
>   uts namespaces to provide different uts info for different servers. If
>   unsure, say N.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Linux implements six different types of namespaces. The purpose of each namespace is to wrap a particular global system resource in an abstraction that makes it appear to the processes within the namespace that they have their own isolated instance of the global resource. One of the overall goals of namespaces is to support the implementation of containers, a tool for lightweight virtualization (as well as other purposes) that provides a group of processes with the illusion that they are the only processes on the system

Referance --
http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/